Getting actual column name in Oracle APEX Collections
while creating a new collection in Oracle APEX and adding members to it based on a query result using this method :
APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS(collectionName) THEN
        APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION(
      p_collection_name => collectionName
    );

-- Execute the dynamic SQL
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
  p_collection_name => collectionName,
  p_query => v_sql_pivot_query,
  p_generate_md5 => 'No'
);

then creating a table to display the query result by:
Select * from APEX_COLLETION WHERE COLLECTION_NAME = 'collectionName';

The probelm is, the actual column names don't appear, instead i get column names like 'C001, C002, etc..'
i need a way to display the acuatl column names dynamically based on the resulted query
To display the column names dynamically based on the resulted query, it is not possible to rename the coulmns manually in the select statment as the columns are changed based on the many parameters

Those are the column names from the apex_collections view. I don't think you can do what you want. You could use dbms_sql to re-parse the query to get the column names/aliases from the metadata, I suppose, but even if you can that assumes the query assigns useful aliases.

"then creating a table to display the query result" do you mean a report in apex?
